Why private repo SPM from Azure devops can't be fetched by xcode since a few days?
Since yesterday, I'm trying to fetch our private SPM repo hosted on Azure via Xcode but without success. It seems something has changed on their side?
(My SSH configuration seems good, and past weeks the fetch was working, so I don't think the problem come from my configuration)
Anyone is experiencing the same here?
When trying to paste the ssh link for the private repo spm, nothing is found by xcode, even so it asked which ssh key to use.

And if you try to fetch manually like cloning the repo with git commands, doest it work?

Yes 'git clone ' is working in Teminal.

Hi there, if trying to clone the repo  into a new path  on your Mac by pasting the ssh url via XCode, will it work?

I got the error : remote: Command git-upload-pack: You’re using ssh-rsa that is about to be deprecated and your request has been blocked intentionally. Any SSH session using SSH-RSA is subject to brown out (failure during random time periods). Please use rsa-sha2-256 or rsa-sha2-512 instead. For more details see https://aka.ms/ado-ssh-rsa-deprecation.
remote: ERROR_SSH_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER (7) (-20)

But I already changed my ssh to rsa-sha2-512. I maybe didn't do the third step : "Change the local SSH configuration so the key generated in point 1 is listed before the SSH-RSA key. This is to ensure more secure algorithms will be used instead of SSH-RSA." But I don't know what to do to resolve that priority list? I already configured my config file in .ssh folder but it seems it's not affected?

What does the config file look like on your Mac? Have you tried the suggestion here?

I don't have these lines in my config file. It's very weird.. I'm generating the sha2-256 (or 512) like asked but... it seems that azure still recognize the new key generated as an old RSA SHA. Idk why... But I only have this problem while fetching via ssh via xcode, don't know why. I'm selecting the good key though. Fetching via terminal is working with no problem.

Hi there, I tested to create ssh key pairs using the commandrsa-sha2-512 with a new user on my Mac, and then uploaded the pub key onto DevOps. I succeeded in cloning repo via git clone command running Terminal but failed via XCode.

Have you or any other user from your organization tried with another/their local accounts to clone via XCode?

Yes same problem with other developer of my organization. It seems xcode is telling to azure that the key used is not rsa sha2, but I don't know why? Any idea?

Yes, from the current behaviors, I appears to me as well that XCode is telling Azure DevOps the wrong encryption method of rsa not rsa sha2. I am not sure if the XCode supports the rsa sha2 key, but from the Azure DevOps side, we don't need to change anything.

I could reproduce the issue when I ran ssh-keygen -t rsa-sha2-256 to generate the key pairs with a new user on Mac; thus no deprecated ssh-rsa key was generated before; after uploading the public key to Azure DevOps, the error occurred when I tried to clone the Azure repo in XCode via SSH. Still the git clone <SSH_URL> command in Terminal succeeded in cloning the Azure repo to Mac.

It appears that XCode is telling Azure DevOps  the wrong encryption method of rsa instead of rsa-sha2 or maybe there is a limit or required configuration of XCode to use rsa-sha2. For this, it is suggested reporting the issue in Apple Developer Forums to engage the insights from the experts of Apple.
As of now, you may consider cloning the HTTPS URL of your Azure Repos   in XCode as A workaround, if possible.

Ok thanks for the confirmation, I created a thread on the forum.
If I have news about the problem, I will post it here.

Thank you so much for your sharing. Cheers!

Here is the link on apple developer forum side : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756916

Thank you a lot for sharing the issue link.

It seems the problem is coming again since this tuesday 26 november but this time with no specific error: An unknown error occured. Failed to start SSH session: Unable to exchange encryption keys (-1)
